# Statistical argument for this cluster measure

Tags: variance, clustering, similarities, metric

This [quick clustering score discussion](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#dedupe.Dedupe.cluster) presents the following single cluster scoring functions:

$$
c_i = 1-\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j}^{N}\left(1-\phi(i,j) \right)^2}{N-1}}
$$

and

$$
C = 1-\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i}^{N}\left(1-c_i \right)^2 (N-1)}{2N^2}}
$$

where $c_i$ is the score for element $i$ in the cluster, $C$ is the total cluster score, $N$ is the size of the cluster, and $\phi(i,j) \in [0,1]$ is a pair-wise similarity between elements $i$ and $j$.

The linked article mentions that variance is used somehow to obtain the formula for $C$.

My questions are:

1. Is this a common measure to score single clusters? If so, are there references.
2. How is variance used to derive the second formula from the first?

Comment: Well, C looks like one of possible measures of a cluster compactness. 1-phi is the distance between two objects in the cluster. One thing that I doudt is needed - is that squaring of 1-phi and then of 1-c. I wonder what might be the reason for the squaring. Do the authors imply that the distance really is (1-phi)^2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight I don't think the second formula is "derived" from the first. The formulae look like just constructed to have the desirable property that "high similarities $\Rightarrow$ large $c_i$, and "large $c_i$ overall $\Rightarrow$ large $C$", and then calibrating numbers to be in the desired $[0,1]$ range. The use of squares will just give low values of $c_i$ (or $\phi(i,j)$ in the first equation) more weight - whether this makes sense depends on the exact definition of $\phi(i,j)$ and the intended interpretation of the outcomes.

It isn't so obvious how variance comes in *(actually it makes sense, see last paragraph)*, but I'd think that this is inspired by the variance formula Var$(X)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j>i}(x_i-x_j)^2$ in the sense that $\sum_i (1-c_i)^2(N-1)$ involves $N(N-1)$ terms, with $(1-\phi(i,j))^2$ occurring twice for every pair $(i, j)$ in $\sum_i (1-c_i)^2$, whereas $\sum_{j>i}(x_i-x_j)^2$ has every distance between $x_i$ and $x_j$ once. That thing is divided by $n^2$ in the variance formula, so here it is divided by $2N^2$ to account for the fact that it's twice the terms, and the squares may make one think of a variance-like thing (for sure it's a measure of within-cluster variation, as is the variance).

Thinking about it more, in fact this seems to be directly based on the variance formula if  $(1-\phi(i,j))^2=(x_i-x_j)^2$ in a Euclidean setting. Then we have
$$
C=1-\sqrt{\frac{(N-1)\sum_i\sum_j(x_i-x_j)^2}{2N^2(N-1)}}=1-\sqrt{V},
$$
with $V$ being the within-cluster variance, so the formula is a generalisation (to more general choices of $\phi(i,j)$) of a "natural" variance-based measure of compactness in case that $(x_i-x_j)^2\in[0,1]$.

I hadn't seen this before and it's certainly not a standard in cluster analysis. The only thing I can imagine is that in applications in a specific field this is used, maybe together with a specific choice of $\phi(i,j)$ (on which it will depend whether this way of generalising from the Euclidean case makes sense).

Comment: +1 for noticing the tie between the sum of squared pairwise euclidean distances with the sum of squared euclidean deviations from the centroid.

Comment: Nice thanks!  This clears things up.  One last thing, where did the in the square root $1/(N-1)$ come from in your formula?  It seems different than the formula in the article but I may have missed a factor somewhere.

Comment: @jman The definition of $c_i$ has a $\frac{1}{N-1}$ under the square root.